How can I prove this approximation of a binomial distribution?
The exercise demands to show that the value of the maximum of the binomial distribution $b(k;n,p)$ is approximately $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi npq}}$ , apparently there is some relation with Stirling's approximation but I am not able to properly establish such link.

Please add your efforts. Hint: The maximum value of the binomial distribution $\text{Binomial}(n,p)$ is obtained at its the mode, which is $\lfloor (n+1)p \rfloor$.
